# Determining ridgeline from DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.4

I want to derive ridgelines from DEM using ArcGIS 10.4. I have tried to use the watershed analysis procedure but the result I have obtained looks weird.

How can I get the ridgelines shapefile?

Comment: Perhaps update your question with  the picture of weird ridge line and procedure description

Answer (score 1):

I think [How To: Identify ridgelines from a DEM](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011289) will be useful for you:

> The instructions provided describe how to identify ridgelines from a
>   DEM. Spatial Analyst and the Hydrology Toolset can be used to identify
>   and extract ridgeline features from an elevation raster (DEM) in the
>   same manner as a stream network can be created by reversing the DEM
>   cell values.